# Kotlin: Как протащить заавтовайренный бин из абстракции в наследника?

Tags: spring, kotlin

Итак, у меня есть класс:

```
open class AbstractMapper<E : AbstractEntity, D : AbstractDto> @Autowired constructor(

        protected val mapper: ModelMapper

) : EntityDtoMapper<E, D>
```

Он имеет в основном конструкторе заавтовайренный бин ModelMapper. Я пытаюсь унаследоваться от этого класса.

```
class UserParamsMapper : AbstractMapper<UserParams, UserParamsDto>()
```

IDE требует от меня объявить в конструкторе AbstractMapper все объявленные в нём до этого поля:

```
No value passed for parameter ModelMapper
```

Подскажите, как это сделать? Или можно заавтовайрить бин в AbstractMapper как-то по-другому и избежать этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class UserParamsMapper @Autowired constructor(mapper: ModelMapper) : AbstractMapper<UserParams, UserParamsDto>(mapper)
```

Думаю, что из объявления класса `AbstractMapper` аннотацию `@Autowired` следует убрать совсем, поскольку параметры конструктору передаете вы сами, а не Spring.